# System.InvalidCastException: 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task, ienumerable

I am trying to perform unit tests of a client that returns a task with a list of elements and iterates them, but what I have tried is not working for me.

```
IEnumerable<ExpenseNote> pendingExpenses = null;
        try
        {
            pendingExpenses = await _expenseNoteService.GetPendingExpenseNotes().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            executionContext.Error($"Step 1-Final: Error when call \"getPendingExpenses()\". Detail: {ex.Message}", true);
            throw;
        }

        if (!pendingExpenses.Any())
        {
            executionContext.Checkpoint("Step 1-Final: There are not pending expenses");
            return;
        }

        int numApproveExpenses = 0;

        executionContext.Checkpoint($"Step 2: Processing {pendingExpenses.Count()} pending expenses");
        foreach (var expenseNote in pendingExpenses)
        {
            if (expenseNote.IsApprovable)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _workflowsRRHHProxy.Approve(expenseNote.Id.ToString());
                    executionContext.Checkpoint($"Step 2.1: Expense with number {expenseNote.Number} has been approved ");
                    numApproveExpenses++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    executionContext.Error($"Step 2.1: Error when call \"Approve()\" with id: {expenseNote.Id} " +
                        $". Detail: {ex.Message}", false);
                    throw;
                }

            }               
        }
```

test example:

```
            // ARRANGE
        var mockExpenseNote = _mockFactory.CreateMock<DomainEntities.ExpenseNote>();
        mockExpenseNote.Expects.One.Method(x => x.IsApprovable).WillReturn(true);

        var expenseNote = mockExpenseNote.MockObject;
        expenseNote.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        expenseNote.Number = "EX-APPROVE";

        var expenseNotes = new List<DomainEntities.ExpenseNote>
       {
            expenseNote
       };
       
        Task<IEnumerable<DomainEntities.ExpenseNote>> task = Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<DomainEntities.ExpenseNote>>(expenseNotes);

        var executionContext = _mockFactory.CreateMock<ITaskExecutionContext>();
        executionContext.Expects.Between(1, 100).Method(method => method.Checkpoint("")).WithAnyArguments();

        _expenseNoteService.Expects.One.Method(method => method.GetPendingExpenseNotes())
            .WithAnyArguments()                
            .WillReturn(task);

        var sut = GetServiceUnderTest();

        // ACT
        await sut.ProcessPendingExpenseNotes(executionContext.MockObject);

        // ASSERT
        _mockFactory.VerifyAllExpectationsHaveBeenMet();
```

but when i execute this test in " .WillReturn(task);" have this error:

**System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression'..**

Can Anyone Help me?

Comment: With `mockExpenseNote.Expects.One.Method(x => x.IsApprovable).WillReturn(true);` your lambda uses a property but you used the `.Method()` method so it expects you to use a method here (or call something else than `.Method()`

Comment: Thx. I tried that you suggest me and it's work. thank you a lot

Comment: I posted it as an answer, consider accepting it if it is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

With `mockExpenseNote.Expects.One.Method(x => x.IsApprovable).WillReturn(true);` your lambda uses a property but you used the `.Method()` method so it expects you to use a method here (or call something else than `.Method()`).